# C# Json with different classes in the same field

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have a problem here.
I'm working with a json that changes the contents of the field.
In the same "Readings" field I can have more options.
I'll show you 2 cases

First one

```
    {
        "type": "voltageReadingsV1",
        "value": {
            "nodeModel": "LS-G6-VOLT-4-EU",
            "readings": [
                {
                    "readingType": "Potentiometer",
                    "channel": 0,
                    "readingData": "442.0150518",
                    "engineeringValue": "22.10075259",
                    "engineeringUnit": "mm"
                },
                {
                    "readingType": "Potentiometer",
                    "channel": 1,
                    "readingData": "372.0518947",
                    "engineeringValue": "18.60259474",
                    "engineeringUnit": "mm"
                },
                {
                    "readingType": "Potentiometer",
                    "channel": 2,
                    "readingData": "495.0417876",
                    "engineeringValue": "24.75208938",
                    "engineeringUnit": "mm"
                },
                {
                    "readingType": "Potentiometer",
                    "channel": 3,
                    "readingData": "392.9279447",
                    "engineeringValue": "19.64639724",
                    "engineeringUnit": "mm"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Second

```
   {
        "type": "geoflexReadingsV1",
        "value": {
            "nodeModel": "AM-H6-VOLT-1-EU",
            "readings": [
                {
                    "sensorNum": "1",
                    "chnY": 100524.254,
                    "chnX": 35224.248
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I can understand the type of json I need to process thanks to the Type field.

the problem is that I don't know how I can do it dynamically.

I prepared a list of all the cases in which the json field can change

```
        public static readonly List<string> ModelTypes = new List<string>()
        {
            "vibratingWireReadingsV1",
            "voltageReadingsV1",
            "slopeIpiReadingsV1",
            "inclinometerReadingsV1",
            "inclinometerReadingsV2",
            "smartMPBXReadingsV1",
            "geoflexReadingsV1",
            "sisgeoV3ReadingsV1",
            "genericModbusReadingsV1",
            "measurandReadingsV1",
            "tiltReadingsV1",
            "picoReadingsV1",
            "laserReadingsV1",
            "tilt90ReadingsV1",
            "til90EReadingsV1",
            "til90EAlertV1",
            "laser90ReadingsV1"
        };
```

I check if there is a match

```
var info = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NodeResponse>>(jsonFormExtern);

var sectionValues = (from x in info where NodeResponse.ModelTypes.Contains(x.Type) select x).FirstOrDefault();
if(sectionValues == null)
{

    continue;
}

var a = sectionValues.Value.DeserializeJson();
```

Inside the DeserializeJson I tried this to parse in this way

```
public  object DeserializeJson()
{
    try
    {
        //Upper case to match with class name, Type is string type
        var tmpType = char.ToUpper(Type[0]) + Type.Substring(1);
        // Get The specific type
        Type targetType = System.Type.GetType("ORAMS_III_Sisgeo_Logger_Data_Service.SisgeoModels." + tmpType);

        if (targetType != null)
        {
            // DeserializeObject, Readings is object type
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Readings.ToString(), targetType);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Type {Type} not found.");
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (JsonException ex)
    {
        // Gestisci l'eccezione se la deserializzazione fallisce
        Console.WriteLine($"Error JSON: {ex.Message}");
        return null;
    }
}
```

This part of code gives me an error, it can't deserialize because the main field is missing

> > Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ORAMS_III_Sisgeo_Logger_Data_Service.SisgeoModels.VoltageReadingsV1' because the type requires a JSON object

Since I already deserialize, the string inside the field is modified, the "Readings : " part is removed.

Can anyone tell me how I can read variable fields?

Comment: Are you constructing this JSON?

Comment: please post your class for `NodeResponse` and `voltageReadingsV1` and `geoflexReadingsV1`. It is not clear what type of inheritance or composition you are expecting

Comment: Knock together a JSON array with one of each of your different types in, and paste the whole lot into QuickType.You'll probably simply end up with one object that represents the wrapping class and another object that represents the reading with a nullable/nully annotated C# property for each of the distinctly encountered json props, which will work

Comment: It seems that you want [polymorphic deserialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-8-0).  This is for System.Text.Json.  With Newtonsoft JSON should also be possible.  A quick search revealed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752/deserializing-polymorphic-json-classes-without-type-information-using-json-net).